# React Map Function within Map Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am very new to react and I can't find information on the issue below.

I have an array of objects and the objects contain arrays. I am trying to use the map function to map elements of the objects and then the map function again to map the elements of the child array.

Please see the code below from within the render method:

```
        <div>
                {this.state.questionarray.map( (item) => (<p>Question {item.questionno}<input type="text" id={item.questionno} />
                                                            <button id={item.questionno} onClick={this.handleAddAnswer}>Add Answer</button>
                                                            {item.answers.map( (ans) => ({ans.answerno}))}</p>
                ) ) }
            </div>
```

With the above I get "Failed to compile... Unexpected token, expected ','". If I remove the inner mapping and replace with item.answers.length then I get the array length which suggests that the array is definitely there. I imagine this to be related to syntax which JSX recognizes. Can anyone help? Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: `{ans.answerno}` is not valid JavaScript (this is not a JSX context). You want `ans => ans.answerno`.

Comment: Please provide sample object.

Comment: Many thanks, that seems to work. How does it work if I want to set ans.answerno as the id property of an input box. I have tried "ans => <input type="text" id=ans.answerno />"

Comment: Is this correct "{item.answers.map( ans => (<input type="text" id={ans.answerno}  />))}"? It seems to be working when I use this syntax.

Comment: Yes the second one is correct. This is inside JSX again, so you need the `{...}` to indicate that the content should be evaluated as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put [Felix's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955175/react-map-function-within-map-function/55955288#comment98562256_55955175) in an answer box, since it's an answer, `{ans.answerno}` should just be `ans.answerno`, because the `map` callback is not a JSX context and `{ans.answerno}` is not valid JavaScript (in an JavaScript expression context).

```
<div>
{this.state.questionarray.map( (item) => (
    <p>Question {item.questionno}
        <input type="text" id={item.questionno} />
        <button id={item.questionno} onClick={this.handleAddAnswer}>Add Answer</button>
        {item.answers.map( (ans) => (ans.answerno  /* <== No {} around this */))}
    </p>
))}
</div>
```